# Azure GUIX automated testing specifically for languages

Tags: automated-tests, azure-rtos

I was checking the feasibilty of Automated testing using Azure GUIX using win32 simulation executable.
I have checked using Inspect but could only find window title bar,close ,maximise, minimise on logs

I also tried recording and play back of macro in GUIX sudio and understood that recorded file is a binary and can't be modified for automation

Please let me know a way to automate GUI.

When I checked Embedded Wizard they have extensive documntation on GUI testing

Answer (score 1):

That is a great question. We have an extensive test harness in place for our own internal regression testing, but we have not yet gone through the steps needed to make this available to our users. Our test harness utilizes Python scripts to obtain each application window handle using the window name, generates events to drive the operation of each window, and compares the canvas memory md5sum with a "golden value" to verify the canvas drawing matches the expected output after each set of command events is executed. I will create a task to get this test harness published and documented for use by our users

Comment: How would you calculate the expected "golden value". If you just run the test to give you the error and then plug that value back into the test then that sounds flawed way of making test.

Comment: Thank you,looking forward for the test harness and documentation

Comment: @ken-maxwell Has any progress been made on releasing your test harness?